# Proving that $U^o=U \setminus \partial{U}$ (Boundary and interior of a set)

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $U^o=U$\ $\partial U$ where $U^o$ is the interior of $U$ and $\partial U$ is the boundary of U where $U$ is a subset of $X$.

I have the definitions $U^o=X \setminus (\overline{X \setminus U})$ and $\partial U=\overline{U} \setminus U^o$

I think that i should use that $A \cap B= A \setminus (X \setminus B)$ and $A \setminus (B \cap C)=(A\setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$ where $A, B$ and $C$ are subsets of $X$

So far i have got $U^o=X \setminus (\overline{X \setminus U})=X \setminus (X \setminus U^o $) and don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma 1.** $U^o\subseteq U$

*Proof.* I leave as an exercise. $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** $\overline{U}=U\cup\partial U$

*Proof.* The "$\supseteq$" inclusion is obvious. For "$\subseteq$" assume that $u\in \overline{U}$ but $u\not\in U$. By *lemma 1* $u\not\in U^o$ and thus $u\in\overline{U}\backslash U^o=\partial U$. $\Box$

> **Lemma 3.** $U^o=U\backslash\partial U$

*Proof.* *Lemma 2* implies that $U\backslash\partial U=\overline{U}\backslash\partial U$ and thus
$$U\backslash\partial U=\overline{U}\backslash\partial U=\overline{U}\backslash\big(\overline{U}\backslash U^o\big)=U^o$$
The last equality because $U^o\subseteq \overline{U}$. $\Box$

Comment: How does lemma 2 imply that $U \setminus \partial{U} = \overline{U} \setminus \partial{U}$?

Comment: @pullofthemoon If $A=B\cup C$ then $A\backslash C=(B\cup C)\backslash C=B\backslash C$. Does this help? Or do you want me to write down details?

Comment: that’s helps! No need to write down the details